# Identify the type of place when getting results from Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I have implemented Google places search.

The problem is that i want to identify that the list of locations returned by the API do contain any airport in it.

As per documentation Google Place do support only these types to identify the place type

- administrative_area_level_1
- administrative_area_level_2
- administrative_area_level_3
- administrative_area_level_4
- administrative_area_level_5
- colloquial_area country establishment
- finance
- floor
- food
- general_contractor
- geocode
- health
- intersection
- locality
- natural_feature
- neighborhood
- place_of_worship
- political
- point_of_interest
- post_box
- postal_code
- postal_code_prefix
- postal_code_suffix
- postal_town
- premise
- room
- route street_address
- street_number
- sublocality
- sublocality_level_4
- sublocality_level_5
- sublocality_level_3
- sublocality_level_2
- sublocality_level_1
- subpremise

There is no airport in the list.

Any idea how can i do it ?

Answer (score 4):

Your list might be incomplete. 
According to https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types there's "airport" in it as well.

Example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=59.4141,24.8334&radius=50&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]

Comment: you can specify the type while searching as you can see type=airport in URL

i dont want this. i want to search every location and check whether the location list (returned by API) includes any airport or not ?

Comment: Remove the &type=airport parameter and then airports also listed. I changed the link in the answer as an example. I also had to set radius=50, because google gives max 20 results and if the range was large then Airport did not fit in the results. Even though the coordinates actually were right on the airport. Maybe that's your problem also?

Comment: kashifasif: note the types you list are "Table 2", and the description of that starts with "The following types may be returned in the results of a place search, **in addition to the types in table 1** above" [emphasis mine].  `airport` is in table 1, and airports will have `airport` in the list of returned types.

Comment: but it dont return airport in type :(

Have you tried it ? 

Please try and share your results

Comment: I am sorry if i am not able to explain 



Let me explain again

Lets say i search for the places with no type parameter in URL, it gives me 30 places, i have to identify how many of them a re airport, how many are hospitals etc

Comment: Add your API key to the link: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=59.4141,24.8334&radius=50&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] 
Search for "Tallinn Airport" record. It has a type "airport".

The problem might be that airports are not in those 30 places. Because if there are too many places in the area then google doesn't give you all of them.

Comment: Are you using pagination to get all the results? 
Check out "pagetoken" parameter in https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search